# c++ convert a word with 4 character stored as char* to an int and vice versa

Tags: c++

I'm searching for a way to convert a word with 4 characters stored as char* to an int and vice versa because i want to transfer the char* through a function which needs an int as argument. Here's an example:

```
char* word = "abcd";
int number;

// write word in number

char* word2;

// write number in word2
```

At the end word2 should be the same as word. It would also help me if you know how to convert it in one direction only.

Comment: How long is your `int` in *bytes*? If it is 4 (a typical value), you cannot store 5 random characters in it.

Comment: And what integer is equal to "hello"? Sounds more like a problem with your program design.

Comment: If a function takes an `int` parameter, then probably it isn't supposed to accept strings. Perhaps what you wrote is not what you meant to ask?

Comment: actually the char* is exactly 4 characters long. And my int is 4 bytes long, right.

Comment: [`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)/[`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess the OP wants to convert a 4-byte string into the correspondig 4-byte integer type, not parse an int from a string.

Comment: _"actually the char* is exactly 4 characters long"_, nope it's actually 5 bytes long.

Comment: I just want to store the bytes from the char* in an int. The function is for saving and handleing data and accepts ints because i normally need to save them.

Comment: @Tim I'm afraid you've been chosing the wrong approach. Are you trying to send numbers over the network, or write to files in a compatible manner for different architectures? Then you should have a look at endianess and the `htonl()`,`ntohl()` function family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it will be converted back on a system with the same endianness

```
number=*((int*)word);
```

Convert back:

```
char word2[5];
*((int*)word2) = number;
word2[4]=0;
```

Comment: exactly what i searched for, thank you

Comment: This is technically undefined behavior since it violates strict aliasing.

Comment: Can you give an example platform / compiler where it wouldn't work?